# SFMC CC an email address in a User Initiated Send definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, cc

I know this is possible on a triggered send definition to CC an email address, but I can't find out if this is possible for a "User Initiated Send".  I have a file drop automation that listens for a file on the FTP, imports the file, and sends the email.  Ideally I'd like to include as part of the file an extra column titled something like "CC".  When the file imports and the email sends, I would like for the send definition to CC whoever is in the CC column.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option to add CC in the user initiated definition (assuming the cc business rule has been enabled for your account). You can set a personalization string such as %%CC_Address%% in the value that is either a DE Column or a variable set in the Ampscript of the message.

**Data Extension Setup:**
[image: Data Extension]

**User Initiated Send Definition Setup:**
[image]